# How do I tell ANTLR to prefer one alternative over the other?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I have the following production:

```
expression
    :   primary # stubLabel
    |   expression '.' Identifier # stubLabel
    |   expression '.' 'this' # stubLabel
    |   expression '.' 'new' nonWildcardTypeArguments? innerCreator # stubLabel
    |   expression '.' 'super' superSuffix # stubLabel
    |   expression '.' explicitGenericInvocation # stubLabel
    |   expression '[' expression ']' # stubLabel
    |   Identifier arguments # namedMethodInvocation
    |   expression '.' Identifier arguments # namedMethodInvocation
    |   expression arguments # unnamedMethodInvocation
    |   // Lots of other patterns...
    ;
```

I wish to make the parser try the `namedMethodInvocation` patterns first before trying `unnamedMethodInvocation`. This does not happen automatically because ANTLR tries to pick the alternative with the longest match, instead of using a first match policy. How can I force it to do this?

**edit:** Sorry, I neglected to post the link to the grammar file above. [Here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4) it is.

Comment: Please post `primary` production rule.

Comment: @saka1029 I'm so sorry, I neglected to link to the full grammar file in my post! The grammar file can be found [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4#L540). The `primary` production rule is [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4#L540).

Comment: In parser rules the alts are tested one by one, top to bottom order (as written in the grammar) and the first matching one wins. Alts ordering is a matter on its own, as it determines quite a few things (e.g. precedence).

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `namedMethodInvocation` to `primary` production rule (before `Identifier`) like this.

```
primary
    :   '(' expression ')'
    |   'this'
    |   'super'
    |   literal
    |   Identifier arguments // namedMethodInvocation
    |   Identifier
    |   typeType '.' 'class'
    |   'void' '.' 'class'
    |   nonWildcardTypeArguments (explicitGenericInvocationSuffix | 'this' arguments)
    ;
```

Or move `primary` to the last in `expression`.

```
expression
    : expression '.' Identifier
    .....
    | Identifier arguments  // namedMethodInvocation
    | expression arguments  // unnamedMethodInvocation
    .....
    | primary
    ;
```

Or insert new rule `primaryOrNamedMethodInvocation`.

```
expression
    : primaryOrNamedMethodInvocation
    | expression '.' Identifier
    .....
    ;

primaryOrNamedMethodInvocation
    : Identifier arguments  // namedMethodInvocation
    | primary
    ;
```

Comment: saka1029, I do not want to do this because it makes no sense for `namedMethodInvocation` to be a primary. `namedMethodInvocation` is supposed to match an expression like `foo.bar()`, which is too complex to be a primary.

Comment: Added another solution.

Comment: saka1029, I do not think that would affect the results because ANTLR chooses an alternative based on how long it is, not its order in the production.

Comment: Added another solution.

Comment: saka1029, closer, thank you for all your help. However, I also need to handle `expression '.' Identifier arguments` for a `namedMethodInvocation` (I posted this in the original question). Moving that into a new rule will not work because it would use indirect left recursion.

Comment: @JamesKo: My understanding is that Antlr resolves *lexical* ambiguity in favour of the longest match, but in the case of *parser* ambiguity it just goes with the first alternative which works. (But I'm not an Antlr expert; I just read that in the manual one time.)